# TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object

Tags: qt, qml, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I am trying to draw Polygon and setting visibility from dataModel when i do that to visibleList i get TypeError : Value is null and could not be converted to an object.

How can i resolve?

```
 Item {
        id: root
        property var dataModel
        property var colorProperty
        property GraphicsOverlay graphicsOverlay
        property bool visibleList: dataModel.isVisible !== undefined ? dataModel.isVisible : true //TYPE ERROR

PolygonBuilder {
        id: polygonBuilder
        spatialReference: SpatialReference.createWgs84()
    }

    Graphic
    {
        id: polygonGraphic
        symbol: fillSymbol
    }

    ListView {
        id: listview
        model: dataModel

        Connections
        {
            target: dataModel
            onDataChanged:
            {
                drawItem()
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set value to `root.dataModel`? It seems that you set it to null somethere, otherwise `root.dataModel` would be undefined.